# Can I masterbate my wife if she is not fasting?

Tags: sex, ramadan

My wife is not Muslim only I am. I want to know can I stimulate her in her time of need even though I’m fasting

Comment: Most fatwa sites expect the Muslim husband to have a leading role in a relationship with a kitabi wife. And even if your wife was a Muslim this wouldn't be permissible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not that would break your fast you may do it after ur done praying maghrib, sexual intercourse breaks your fast and if you do this during Ramadan you have indeed committed a major sin.

Comment: He said HIS wife.

Comment: No it is not because masturbating his wife doesn't always involve intercourse